# Xcode 5- Connecting button to action w/out File Owner

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button

I'm trying to connect a button to an action.

ViewController.h:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed;
```

ViewController.m:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Pressed!");
    }
```

When I click control and drag the button, there's no option to select the 'buttonPressed' action. Also, I've noticed people saying to drag it to 'FileOwner' but I don't see that option on my screen. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you doing this in Storyboard, or in the .m file?

Comment: Try googling how to add a "UIButton in Xcode?"

Comment: I'm in storyboard right now.

Comment: Check out for some YouTube video to learn this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These screen shots should help you find this.

On the interface builder (storyboard/xib) on the left hand side of the view where your view objects are listed, press on the light orange coloured box called 'file's owner" at the top... see screen shot -

[image: Press files owner label here]

When you select this, please look at the right hand side panel, the utilities and make sure the third button is highlighted (see top of screen shot blue icon)....

[image: Utilities Panel where Files Owner details can be found]

Here you will see Custom Class and within the text box (highlighted in blue here) is the name of the view controller class file that owns the view. If it's empty, this means you'll need to put the name of your view controller class file in here. Once this has been done, you will be able to connect buttons etc.

I hope this explanation helps.

Cheers, Jim.

EDIT - **

On storyboard the view of file's owner button can be found at the bottom of the view controller. Please see screen shot, press the light orange coloured square at the bottom, which is the and look to the third tab on the utilities panel again.

Cheers
[image: Files Owner From VC on StoryBoard]

Comment: Jim, thank you. Your first screenshot is what I'm having trouble with. I don't see that tab or dropdown. All I see is 'View Controller Scene', which leads to 'View Controller', 'First Responder', and 'Exit'.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you where to find it on storyboard. Thanks